# Android can't find files external device connecting second time

Tags: java, android, usb, motorola

I know this is a long shot, but I'm all out of ideas.

Basically, I have a Motorola TC55 that needs to mail a .pdf file from a TempTale 4 USB (connected by USB to the device).

The app itself is already working great, so no issues there, but here's the catch. When the TempTale 4 is connected for the first time, it displays the files in the /udisk directory so everything works great, but if I disconnect the TempTale and reconnect it the /udisk directory stays empty.

The phone doesn't recognise the TempTale as a USB device when connecting the second time and instead displays a message along the lines of "the SD card can now be safely removed" as soon as the TempTale is connected. I've looked everywhere but the files are nowhere to be found.

The only thing that helps is rebooting the TC55, which is a real pain in the ass if you're going to have to do that every time before being able to upload the temperature statistics.

It's running Android 4.1.2 and it's a company phone so I can't root it to try some coded (un)mounting magic to see if that helps.

Any help or ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated, because I'm baffled by this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the TempTale device is not handling the USB disconnect properly. Does it help if you unmount the udisk before you disconnect it the first time?

Comment: That's kind of part of the problem.
There's no option to unmount the usb in the storage settings and the "usb mass storage connected" immediately disappears from the drop-down menu ... so I can't unmount the device manually, and I don't have the root permissions to do it programmatically.